# C++, Время, ctime

Tags: c++

Как реализовать увеличение переменной на 1 за одну секунду?
И является ли хорошим решение с циклом?

```
k=k+1;
sleep('1000');
k=k+1;
```

Comment: зависит от того, будут ли от этого кода зависеть жизни астронавтов?

Comment: Во первых функция `sleep()` из стандартной библиотеки принимает целое, а то что вы написали - это "многобайтный символ", который компилятор допускает, но подразумевает под этим совсем не то что вам нужно.  И это время в секундах, а не в миллисекундах.

Во вторых, если нужно выполнять какое-то действие точно раз в секунду, необходимо смотреть текущее время, так как функция sleep работает не точно, и со временем в цикле ошибка будет накапливаться.

Если же нужно ничего не делать k секунд, то зачем инкремент в цикле, не проще ли написать `sleep(k)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если делать в лоб, то поток создать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval){
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true){
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}


void do_something(){
   // здесь увеличивайте значение
}

int main() {
    timer_start(do_something, 1000);

    while(true);
}
```

Ваш код, в случае выполнения в основном потоке, будет блокировать всё.

Можно ещё использовать `libevent`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <event.h>

void inc_value(int fd, short event, void *arg){
    // здесь увеличиваем переменную
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
  struct event ev;
  struct timeval tv;

  tv.tv_sec = 1;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  event_init();
  evtimer_set(&ev, inc_value, NULL);
  evtimer_add(&ev, &tv);
  event_dispatch();

  return 0;
}
```

Если используете boost, то там есть [таймер](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html).

Если уж для вас нормально, что будет блочиться основной поток, то:

```
int k = 0;
int limit = 5;
while(1) {
   sleep(1000); 
   ++k;
   if( k >= limit)
      break;
}

call_me_after_all();
```

Comment: Мне еще далеко до такого, но в программе не выполняется много действие сразу. Можно что-нибудь попроще.

Comment: @GoldenCobra у вас программа последовательна. Если вы где-то напишите `sleep(1000)` в основном потоке - это значит, что в течении секунды программа вообще ничего делать не сможет

Comment: Она не должна ничего делать в это время, но по достижении определенного значения k она вызывает функцию. Извиняюсь за некоторые глупости, только начал учиться.

Comment: @GoldenCobra сколько раз надо инкрементить? Заверните в `while` тогда. Сейчас обновлю ответ.